# Storing multiple values for each user

Tags: mysql, database-design

Let's say I want to make something where each user can add multiple 'things'. I want to load these things when the user logs in and each user has its own things, so they don't get to see, or edit, the things of the other users. What is the best way to save this data in a MySQL table?

So let's say that I want to add just a simple text. Each user can add as many of these as they like. However, all of these contain additional information like the data, and other options the user can use.

I don't think it is a good idea to have a column for each of these, because the user can add an unlimited amount of them, and that eventually you would end up with a whole lot of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you already have a `user` table. It sounds like this would logically be a `user_thing` table, where each row defines one "thing" for one user.

Each `user_thing` record usually primary key) would include the unique ID (usually the primary key) from the `user` table, tying that row to a particular user.

`user` would have one row per user, but `user_thing` could have multiple rows for each user (or just one, or none, depending on what the user has chosen to set up).